# Matplotlib: Error processing line 1 of /usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/basemap-1.3.7-py3.11-nspkg.pth:

Tags: matplotlib

Im still learning my way around linux and using the terminal. Today i was trying to install a data processing program and had some issues with matplotlib. I kept getting "matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 module not found" I tried the pip uninstall command, dnf uninstal, rpm -e matplotlibe. Nothing worked, so i ended going into the directory and manually removing it. After that was done i also remove the older versions of python and kept the 3.11 one and use "pip3 instal...." after that i was able to install the data processing software and it ran great. How ever i do get an error now in the terminal:

Error processing line 1 of /usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/basemap-1.3.7-py3.11-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<frozen site>", line 186, in addpackage

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 570, in module_from_spec
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Im not sure exactly what it means or how to fix it. Aside from that everything seems to run smooth. Im running Fedora 38. Any help is greatly appreciated

So far tried updating matplotlib, mp-tool install, sudo dnf matplotlib install